# Как получить значение атрибута, если в исходном коде написано {{= flyingStatus(it.m_status) }}?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, cheerio

Если просматривать исходный код страницы, то вместо "обычного" значения атрибута написано следующее (class = конечно не в самом атрибуте, а для наглядности):

```
class = "bma-fly flying {{= flyingStatus(it.m_status) }}
```

Если после загрузки страницы я нажимаю Inspect, то узнаю, что там написано:

```
class = "bma-fly flying flying-won-team2 flying-past"
```

Вопрос, как извлечь информацию из тега с таким атрибутом?
Просто, если я использую "**cheerio**", то он такое не видит (или я не правильно делаю).

```
const $ = cheerio.load(html);
console.log($("bma-fly.flying.flying-won-team2.flying-past")); // nothing
```

Еще на сайте подключена **cloudflare's anti-ddos** защита, не знаю, важно это или нет.

Comment: придется дубликат создавать...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, on page you have:

```
<div class = "bma-fly flying flying-won-team2 flying-past"> la la la </div>
<div class = "bma-fly flying flying-won-team2 flying-past"> kyrlik kyrkik </div>
<div class = "bma-fly flying flying-won-team2 flying-past"> bo bo bo </div>
<div class = "bma-fly flying flying-won-team2 flying-past"> info </div>
<div class = "bma-fly flying flying-won-team2 flying-past"> privet chelovek </div>
```

And you want see all information.
Code for that with use node.js and puppeteer:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
var fs = require('fs');

var link = "www. IIpuBeT Dpyr . com";

(async () => {
  console.log("Get info");
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto(link);
   });
   const text = await page.evaluate(() => {
      return [...document.body.querySelectorAll('.bma-fly.flying.flying-won-team2.flying-past')]
               .map(element => element.innerText)
               .join('\n');
    });

  console.log(text);
  fs.writeFileSync("nameFile.txt" , text);
  browser.close();
})();
```

more informationt there: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/1897